# Change value of dictionary if it is in another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of generated dictionaries. One is like a template structured like:

```
list_of_dicts_template = [{'year': 0, 'week': 38, 'count_tickets': 0}, {'year': 0, 'week': 39, 'count_tickets': 0}]...
```

And another is a dictionary with values that we know:
`known_values_list = [{'year': 2022, 'week': 39, 'tickets': 47}, {'year': 2022, 'week': 40, 'tickets': 3}]...` 
My problem is, I want to mix them in one list of dictionaries. Where if value of key 'week' is in list of dicts  **known_values_list**, it will replace whole dict in **list_of_dicts_template**.

So the expected list of dicts would look like:
`final_list = [{'year': 0, 'week': 38, 'count_tickets': 0}, {'year': 2022, 'week': 39, 'count_tickets': 47}, {'year': 2022, 'week': 40, 'tickets': 3}]...`
`

I actually don't know how to approach this problem. If I had only dicts without array, I would do something like:

```
for sub in dicts_template:
    if(sub in known_values):
        dicts_template[sub] = known_values[sub]
```

But if it's in arrays, I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
for i,d1 in enumerate(list_of_dicts_template):
    for j, known_value_d in enumerate(known_values_list):
        if known_value_d['week'] == d1['week']:
            list_of_dicts_template[i] = known_value_d
            del known_values_list[j]
```

To add only delete the element in the `known_values_list`, if  there shouldn't be any duplicate weeks in the `list_of_dicts_template`.

Comment: Does not provide a way to have the week  = 40 in the final result

Comment: You're right from a theoretical standpoint. But being that `list_of_dicts_template` ends with three dots and by the fact that it's called a template I think it would already include week 40.

Comment: The problem was lacking enough info for building a good solution.  
@CodeKorn nice usage of enumerate, arguably you could also "break" inside the if